# Can I write unit test for the scala code that defines my SBT build?

Tags: sbt

I'd like to add a unit-test like verification about the properties of the build I've defined.  For example, a unit to verify that `libraryDependencies` doesn't contain any dependency to `foo.bar`

I know how to exclude `foo.bar`, but I would really like a separate test to guard against it being accidentally added back.  Is that possible or should I just use `excludeDependencies` and guard against changes to it?